# Slideshow for images in one node

Tags: media, views

I am having an image field which takes unlimited number of images in the content type.
now I need to create a slideshow (using views slideshow possibly) for those images in one node.
any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: I get the impression that you haven't done much research at all prior to asking the question.

Comment: Hi Letharion, 
Yes I did. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4417/10642 this was the only solution related to my query which was a bit messy to me.I just want a simple approach to solve this.

Comment: Per the (new) on-hold reason, please can you narrow down what it is you're actually asking (bearing in mind that we can't provide a tutorial for an entire feature of your site). Adding in what you've already physically tried would be of great benefit and would help you to get better, more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Field slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module that is probably easier to configure than [Views slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) when all your images are in a single field.

Views slideshow offers more flexibility in that you can source your images from essentially anywhere, but that doesn't seem to be useful in your situation.

Comment: there will be many nodes in that content type, so when I land on the node the images should be in the slideshow format, so every node  has its own (which could be done using contextual filters), can I do the same with what you're suggesting?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the entire module. :)